# Почему метод в Ruby понимает что именно в него передают, если это не переменная объекта?

Tags: ruby, конструктор

Доброго времени суток. Изучаю Ruby, не пинайте сильно, только начал.

Почему в методе say_hi в параметре (в скобках) переменная не типа "@name" (переменная объекта), но метод все-равно работает? Насколько понял, потому что есть attr_accessor, но ведь в параметре не переменная объекта, как метод понимает что в него передают?

```
class Person
    attr_accessor :name
    def initialize(name)
        @name = name
    end
    def say_hi
        puts "hi #{name}"
    end
end

person_one = Person.new("Ivan")
person_one.say_hi
person_one.name = "Petr"
person_one.say_hi
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
attr_accessor :name
```

Добавляет в ваш класс метод

```
  def name
        @name
  end
```

Поэтому вы можете обращаться к переменно используя этот метод.

Comment: а почему срабатывает без собаки?

def say_hi
        puts "hi #{name}"
    end

Comment: Без @ - это вызов метода. С @ - это обращение к переменной.